# Need idea to manage capabilities per modules

Tags: python, algorithm

Project has 40+ modules which support different set of features.
To not duplicate 200+ tests 40+ times need to introduce mapping to manage which test is applicable to which module (some tests would apply to almost all modules when some specific tests only for 2-3).

Idea I tried is to add an annotation to each test like

> @capability(GroupA.SubGroupA.SubSubGroupA)

and create config file per module where supported capabilities are listed.
E.g.

> module #1:
>   - GroupA.SubGroupA
>   - ...

(would support all tests with GroupA.SubGroupA independent on deeper SubSubGroups...)

> module #2:
>   - GroupA.SubGroupA.SubSubGroupA.SubSubSubGroupA
>   - ...

(which would be parsed to means that module does not support all features from GroupA, or even from SubGroupA but only one specific SubSubSubGroup)

Comment: "independent on" is ambiguous. It could potentially mean "dependent on" or "independent of," which have opposite meanings. Do you mean module #1 should also test SubSubGroupA  and SubSubSubGroupA (and all sub-modules) or not?

Comment: yes, module #1 should support all SubSub... under specified SubGroupA